# Looking for word to describe refillable cards at arcades/casinos

Tags: single-word-requests

Those cards that you can pay for and you can refill with money, and at arcades/casinos you simply take the card and swipe and you can play. It's like the alternative for inserting a coin and playing.

What are those called?

Comment: They are often called "reloadable" cards - a synonym of refillable

Answer (score 1):

It is a ***swipe card***:

> a plastic card that you slide through a machine in order to be allowed into a building, pay for something, etc.
>   <sub>[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/swipe-card)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean a *[prepaid credit/debit card](https://usa.visa.com/pay-with-visa/cards/prepaid-cards.html)*?  Some places (notably [Costco](https://www.costco.com/Costco-Cash-Card.product.10024438.html)) call them *[cash cards](https://www.globalcashcard.com/)*.

Answer (score 0):

One name is "[stored value cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored-value_card)". This applies to cards used in transit systems such as Toronto's Presto Card and Hong Kong's Octopus Card as well as cards used in certain food courts and such like.